# In Scala how can I advise my own methods?

Tags: scala, traits, mixins, linearization

I want to do this:

```
trait Renderable {
    def render: String
}

trait Parens extends Renderable {
    abstract override def render = "(" + super.render + ")"
}

object Foo extends Renderable with Parens {
    def render = "Hello"
}
```

But this does not work because the linearization order puts Parens after Foo
(Foo always comes, of course) so Parens can't advise Foo.render.

I end up doing this:

```
trait FooRender {
    def render = "Hello"
}

object Foo extends FooRender with Parens {
}
```

But sometimes I really don't want to do that because it breaks things up. As
far as I can tell, linearization order is the only thing getting in the way,
but I don't know a way to change that. What might make this cleaner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about separating the presentation logic (`render`) and the actual contents (`value`)?

```
trait Renderable {
  def value : String
  def render = value // default presentation logic, simple rendering.
}

trait Parens extends Renderable {
  override def render :String = "(" + value + ")" // parens rendering.
}

object Foo extends Parens {
  def value = "Hello"
}

println(Foo.render) // prints '(Hello)'
```

---

### Edit

Found a way you can do pretty much what you wanted, check it out:

```
trait Renderable {
  def render: String
}

trait Parens extends Renderable {
  abstract override def render = "(" + super.render + ")"
}

class Foo extends Renderable {
  def render = "Hello"
}

val foo = new Foo with Parens
println(foo.render)
```

You can't use an `object` since you need to implement the trait at creation time, but if you can control the instance creation then this might work :).

I'm pretty sure it's not possible to do it otherwise (someone please correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Because then traits don't stack anymore. That's another option I've used occasionally, though.

Comment: what do you mean by "traits don't stack" ?

Comment: The problem with the code you posted is that your `Foo` already has the `render` method defined, so there's no need to go up the call hierarchy looking for another implementation. It will always execute the `Foo` method

Comment: I mean that if Parens has `value` in the "inside" and `render` on the "outside" it can't be used like a mixin; ie, it cannot be composed with other traits defined along the same pattern, which is really what I'm going for.

Comment: What is "stackable" here is the rendering behavior. The value is not

Comment: Right... but if Parens refers to `value`, then it isn't stackable anymore.

Comment: I do like the idea of separating the presentation logic out with a trait... in fact many times this limitation has forced me into making a better design. There are times though when I wish I could get around it.

Comment: Found a new way of doing it, check it out!