# Implementation of abstract traits in with clause

Tags: scala, traits, scala-2.9

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Scala how can I advise my own methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863947/in-scala-how-can-i-advise-my-own-methods)

Assume:

```
trait SomeAbstractTrait {
    val transform : Int => Int
}
```

Why does the following work:

```
new SomeClass() with SomeTrait with SomeAbstractTrait {
   val transform : Int => Int = (x) => x*2
}
```

while

```
new SomeClass() with SomeAbstractTrait {
   val transform : Int => Int = (x) => x*2
} with SomeTrait
```

does not?

Having to declare traits with a single abstract function object before I can use them is a bit annoying and since the first version works I assume I just got the syntax wrong?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  What are you trying to do?  And what makes you think that the second bit of code is preferable to the first?

Comment: @dhg I'm trying to avoid having to write `trait X1 extends SomeAbstractTrait {}` and then use `X1` since all those implementations of SomeAbstractTrait are all only used once. Since the sequence of traits does matter the first one isn't equivalent to the second one (if the second one would compile and do the obvious), so it's not really about "preferable".

Comment: And `new SomeClass() with SomeAbstractTrait with SomeTrait` isn't what you want?  Maybe you could edit your question to explain more completely.  For example, put in a full, working example.  Also you reference a "abstract function object", but there are no functions shown.

Comment: @dhg I wanted to keep it short, but since that's causing confusion I've added the declaration for `SomeAbstractTraint` and the actual implementation of it. `with SomeAbstractTrait` does not work as it's abstract and need its implementation to be useful.

Comment: @Owen Yes seems to be the same, too bad that it doesn't work. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: Actually I think this would be a duplicate question.

Comment: @Owen Right you are, completely forgot about that. Luckily one can vote to close their own question.